# Pimcore memory limit error

Tags: php, pimcore, pimcore-v5

I am trying to get pimcore v.5 work and whenever there's some issue with installation, database or extensions, I just get something like this:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 147456 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/lings.ch/staging.lings.ch/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Is there a way to get better debug message? With this it's impossible to understand whether to search for solution.

Answer (score 1):

That is more or less the error message you need. The memory limit is set too low. 
You should increase the memory_limit setting in your php.ini.

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

The Pimcore documentation states that 128M should be enough. I would still try with 512M, at least for the setup.

Comment: No, I afraid it's not that easy. It crashes regardless how much memory you give it, you can see that it's actually 1GB in my example. To be clear - I was able to install pimcore and it's working, I am now only telling about situations when something goes wrong. In this case there's nothing that could hint me on what that is.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, I see you already have the limit set to 1GB. This is though somehow related to composer, but I am not sure what could cause such high memory usage.

Comment: Try running this command in your document root and check if this helps in any way:
`composer update --profile -vvv`

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocation issue occurs when memory limit is too high or too less. Please make sure Memory_Limit is not equal to -1. Try to set memory_limit = 1024M.
Also verify below in php.ini 
 - upload_max_size 
 - post_max_size 
 - upload_max_filesize 
 - max_execution_time
 - max_input_time